# How to setup policies in RabbitMQ using SpringAMQP?

Tags: rabbitmq, high-availability, spring-amqp

I am working on developing clustered environment with 1 disk and 2 ram nodes. Can anyone please explain how to configure policies using Spring AMQP annotations to create mirrored queue in RabbitMQ broker.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

RabbitMQ 3.0 moved the configuration of HA (mirrored) queues from queue arguments to policies.

Policies cannot be configured using the AMQP protocol, and hence the Spring-AMQP project can't be used to configure them via configuration any longer.

There are ReST APIs however, or you can use the rabbitmqctl command.

See the [RabbitMQ Page on configuring HA Queues](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) for more information, and [the Spring AMQP Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e209) about configuring the connection factory with multiple brokers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Russell. Is there any approach to implement high-availability using Spring-AMQP? does it support ha or not?

Comment: Yes; you provide the CachingConnectionFactory a list of addresses (for the servers). But you have to configure the HA queues on the brokers.

Comment: Addresses - 
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
 CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
 connectionFactory.setAddresses("abc:5672,xyz:5672");
 connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
 connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
 return connectionFactory;
}